# Parse Bibtex files

Tags: php, javascript

I would like to parse the following `bibtex` string or maybe a whole `.bib` file using php or javascript.

Any suggestions?

The string looks like:

```
@article{Sng:2010:PMW:1750585.1750678,
 author = {Sng, Colin T. S. and Manlove, David F.},
 title = {Popular matchings in the weighted capacitated house allocation problem},
 journal = {J. of Discrete Algorithms},
 issue_date = {June, 2010},
 volume = {8},
 number = {2},
 month = jun,
 year = {2010},
 issn = {1570-8667},
 pages = {102--116},
 numpages = {15},
 url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jda.2008.11.008},
 doi = {10.1016/j.jda.2008.11.008},
 acmid = {1750678},
 publisher = {Elsevier Science Publishers B. V.},
 address = {Amsterdam, The Netherlands, The Netherlands},
 keywords = {Maximum popular matching, Polynomial-time algorithm, Popular matching     problem, Priorities, Strict preference lists},
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't quite remember the BibTeX syntax, but I'd suggest to convert the syntax to make it parsable by `JSON.parse`, like this:

```
var bibjson = bibtex.replace(/(\w+)\s*=\s*\{/g,"\"$1\": \"")
          .replace(/\}(?=\s*[,\}])/g,"\"")
          .replace(/@(\w+)\s*\{([^,]*)/,"{\"$1\": \"$2\"");
var bibobj = JSON.parse(bibjson);
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I believe there is an error in your code. I cannot run it. There is an error in the first line. `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/', expecting ')' in /homepages/26/d94605010/htdocs/lz/php/index.php(153) : eval()'d code on line 21`

Comment: I gave you a Javascript solution, not a PHP one.

Comment: Is it possible to put it on jsfiddle?

Comment: Sure: http://jsfiddle.net/hFKjX/ I made some little modification to you BibTeX source, though. Namely, i put "jun" between braces, and deleted the last comma before the closing brace. If you think your BibTeX source will have values not embraced by curly braces, the code has to be modified.

Comment: I'd like to use your solution in a program I'm writing and I want to attribute all code I didn't write to its original author. Did you create this code yourself? It's so elegant.

Comment: Sure, I did this on my own. Feel free to copy, edit and share it, and if you want to cite me as the author, well... I'll surely don't mind :)

Comment: @tobibeer It *does* work, but limited to salamis' question. For other test cases, the code should be adapted.