# BibTeX format query

Tags: php, javascript, reference, bibtex

Hi I am trying to write a parser at the moment for BibTeX records in order to store all of the relevant information on a database and to generate formatted references based on the records in question.

I was hoping to find out if somebody here actually knew what each format in Bibdesk was and what it stood for because there appears to be some ambiguity on that front. Are Bibdesk formats consistent across platforms also?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at [JabREF](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/), which is a Java-based BibTeX editor that does some parsing and representation of BibTeX entries.

There are some BibTeX record types that are universal, but there are also several that are specific to the macros rendering them, so you might be out of luck if you want a total list of 
records and their semantics.

Also, try looking at [Parse Bibtex files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768747/parse-bibtex-files)